# How to exit an application properly

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

Usually, I will just use `Environment.Exit(code)` to exit an application. (Usually through a button click.) But I would like to know is it the proper way to exit, ie, releasing memory etc etc...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just `Close()` all active/existing forms and the application should exit.

Comment: ok. thanks. `close()` will make sure that memory are release right?

Comment: Garbage collection should kick in and handle everything.

Comment: The NT kernel will clean up when a process ends, but with .net, there are many .net processes per NT process, so who knows what will happen. I have seen a long delay before resources are freed in .net. When they would be instant with a native application, or one .net per native process.

Comment: `error BC30815: 'close' is not declared. File I/O functionality is available in the 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' namespace.`

Answer (score 25):

[Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) does the trick too: any forms you have can still cancel this for instance if you want to present a save changes dialog.

Comment: When using this, the closed event doesn't get called.

Answer (score 19):

```
Application.Exit
    End
```

will work like a charm The "END" immediately terminates further execution while "Application.Exit" closes all forms and calls.

Best regrads,

Comment: That's a good way to leave objects in memory without proper disposal.

Comment: @HackSlash Wouldn't the GC get it after a while?

Comment: @laancelot it depends upon the object type. EXAMPLES: If you have opened an external application it will remain open, It could be both open and invisible to the user and they won't be able to close it without task manager. Some database connections can be left in a state where you have a lock on a DB object that won't be released without reboot. Never use `End` for any reason. There isn't a situation where it is needed.

Comment: `error BC30451: 'Application' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Answer (score 2):

In a console application, just return from the main program, in a UI-Application Close() all active Forms.

Memory from managed objects will be handled by the .NET Framework, you don't need to care about this.

If you use classes which implement IDisposable (like database connections, for example), you should call Dispose() on them when you no longer need them (preferred way: a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)-Statement).

If you use such resources globally (like private members in your form), your form should implement the IDisposable pattern to release these resources on the Close()-call. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()

This is better in case you are using another namespaces and objects with the name "Application"

Comment: This was  the  one I needed. When using the Application Framework in a VB.Net winforms application you get another `Application` without the `Exit()` method. Adding the full namespace solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is used in **Visual Basic** when prompting a user to exit the application:

```
Dim D As String

D = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", vbYesNo+vbQuestion,"Thanking You")

If D =  vbYes Then 
Unload Me
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Me.Close

Application.Exit

End

Process immediately terminated in Task Manager Processors!
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I start Outlook and then close it

```
Dim ol 

Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Starts Outlook

ol.quit 'Closes Outlook
```

Answer (score 0):

VB 2019 has an option in the project setup that causes the project to close if the startup form closes.

Answer (score -1):

```
me.close()
```

You should try this.
I guess it will work.

Comment: This closes the *form*, and won't close the program if multiple forms are open.