# Hard Time Closing Forms

Tags: vb.net

Alright, so I am writing a program in VB that has 2 forms. These forms are to rotate via button click and be able to close the entire program no matter what form is being shown. As of now, what is happening is, that if I launch the program and click X to close, it will close. However, if I click the button to show Form2, the close button X doesn't close the program and the program keeps running. Also consider that if I change from Form1 to Form2, then back to Form1, Form1 no longer has the ability to close the program like it does before the button click. Any help? This the code I am using in each for, minus the close commands. I feel like the command for closing the forms needs to be outside of the Private Sub for the Button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Switches to Daily
    Dim FirstForm As New Form1
    FirstForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    'TODO: Close Program on X
End Sub
```

Comment: Here you can see How to close application properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276069/how-to-exit-an-application-properly

Comment: In addition to mggSoft's comment, [My.Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/eh13dca9(v=VS.90).aspx) Property can be useful in this situation

Comment: Use Me.Close() instead.  And change a setting: Project > Properties > Application > Shutdown mode.

Comment: Ill try all of these whenever I get back home and let you know what worked.

Comment: I was hoping Hans's option would have worked, but you can only select one or the other, not both. And the others don't work either. Like I posted to Kash, there has to be a custom Sub that I have to make, because Form_Load and Button_Click are not the places for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
me.Close()       ' Will close the form. 
application.Exit ' Will close the application.
```

Read through [.NET End vs Form.Close() vs Application.Exit Cleaner way to close one's app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976380/) for a better description for this. Some good learning.

Comment: I tried those, but maybe I was putting them in the wrong spot. Ill try again whenever I get home and give that a read.

Comment: Ok so I tried this with no luck. Form.Close(), End, and Application.Exit are not working the way I want them to. The all prevent the form from opening. There has to be a custom Sub that you have to make for this, because Form_Load and Button_Click are definitely not the places for it.