# Close VB.Net application from Startup event

Tags: vb.net, startup

I am writing a vb.net application and am trying to close the application gracefully from the startup event if there are certain errors.

Is there a way to do this?

At the moment I have the "Enable Application Framework" checkbox selected, and all code is in the "Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup" event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to exit an application properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276069/how-to-exit-an-application-properly)

Comment: Not a lot of details to go on, but if you dont like how things are going, `e.Cancel = True` will prevent the app/mainform from starting up.  Always check event args when coding in event procedures

Comment: This is not a dupe of that one by the way.  The OP is trying to end the app before there is a MainForm to `Close` or an `Application` object to `.Exit`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way as I have always been able to use Application.Exit() but you could try Enviroment.Exit(). The differences are explained here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to close during the Application.StartUp event is to set e.Cancel = True, since at that time there is no Form to Close nor a Application object to use Application.Exit

Comment: `Cancel` is not a member of `StartupEventArgs`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my strategy and removed the "Enable Application Framework" and changed to my startup object to Sub Main()

A brief example is:

```
Sub Main(byval args() as string)

'Do my checking here
...


If MyCheckingFails then Return

Application.Run(MyMainForm)

End Sub
```